# How to exchange tuple elements with list elements?

Tags: python, list, tuples, mapping

I have a problem regarding tuples and lists in Python:

Suppose I have tuples of the following form

```
lambda21 = ((0,1),(0,),(),(0))
lambda22 = ((0,),(1,),(0,),(1,))
```

Now, I have four lists namely

```
 u1 = [p,r,t]
 l1 = [q,s,u]
 u2 = [v,x]
 l2 = [w,y]
```

Now, I want to convert my tuple elements into the elements of the lists, where u1 corresponds to lambda21[0], l1 to lambda21[1], u2 to lambda21[2] and l2 to lambda21[3].

And the number in each lambda is the position of the element in the lists and should be exchanged against that element, where the result should be

```
lambda21 = ((p,r),(q,),(),(w))
lambda22 = ((p,),(s,),(v,),(y,))
```

Does any one know how to do such an exchange maybe using list-comprehension?

Comment: I really can't follow what you're asking sorry

Comment: I just want to convert the elements in my tuples into the elements which are in the four lists, where the number inside of the tuple is the corresponding index of the letter in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brought in numpy since you can index with a list on arrays (but not lists).

```
lambda21 = ((0,1),(0,),(),(0,))
lambda22 = ((0,),(1,),(0,),(1,))

u1 = ['p','r','t']
l1 = ['q','s','u']
u2 = ['v','x']
l2 = ['w','y']

lists = [u1, l1, u2, l2]
[np.array(x)[list(y)] for x, y in zip(lists, lambda21)]
```

---

Without numpy you can use another comprehension, may or may not be easier to read:

```
[[x[t] for t in y] for x, y in zip(lists, lambda21)]
```

Output:

```
[['p', 'r'], ['q'], [], ['w']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lists = [u1, l1, u2, l2]
lambda21 = tuple(tuple(lists[n][index] for index in t) for n, t in enumerate(lambda21))
```

Tell me if this works because I can’t test it right now.